# Export data to CSV in server pagination / sorting / filtering mode

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am trying to export the [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) data to CSV.

The issue is, it exports only the visible data **OR** the in-memory data received from HTTP call while considering `paginationPageSize`, `maxBlocksInCache`, `cacheBlockSize` etc. in the grid. Not the entire data-set.

I went through below links, but couldn't get much help.

1. [[export] Export to CSV all pages in Client side
   Pagination](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/763)
2. [agGrid
   data
   export](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#gsc.tab=0)

Is there any way we can achieve this? Or this is altogether not possible?

Comment: i think only the data visible in the viewport can be exported to csv/excel because the entire data is not available at one time for server side pagination.

Comment: the data is loaded on scroll by demand.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i solved this -

1. fetch all rows you need from your data source
2. clone gridapi object
3. grab the serverside cache from the cloned gridapi
4. process it so its filled with your feched data
5. run export to excel method on the cloned gridapi
6. ...
7. PROFIT

const gapi = cloneDeep(this.gridApi);                                     // clone gridApi

const blocks = gapi['serverSideRowModel'].rootNode.childrenCache.blocks;  // object notation to suppress private warning/err

```
  // swap rows cache with fetched data
  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < Math.ceil(results.length/this.paginationPageSize); i++) {
    // we alter relevant block, or if it is not loaded yet we clone 1st one and alter it
    const block = blocks[i] || cloneDeep(blocks[0]);  
    block.rowNodes.forEach(n => n.data = results[j++]);
    blocks[i] = block;
  }
  gapi['serverSideRowModel'].rootNode.childrenCache.blocks = blocks;

  gapi.exportDataAsExcel(params);
```

Comment: This looks helpful, can you please add some more context to it. in code wise, thanks

Comment: This is broken as of version 30+ . Had it working in version 28.

Answer (score 0):

I had the above accepted answer working in v28 using the SSR model, however it broke in our upgrade to V30. All of our sorting and filtering is done in elastic search on the server so I didn't test it with client side sorting and filtering but this works and you don't have to clone the API which is IMHO a much better solution.

I will say that AG Grid should offer something that does this but one Github post from 2016 and another August 2023 says it "is coming" but apparently winter doesn't come wherever they are.

```
const exportListData = React.useCallback(
    async (params = {}) => {
      const { api, columnApi, columnKeysToExport, exportAs } = params;
      setIsExportingListData(true);
      const fetchConfig = {
        query: getDataGQLQuery,
        variables: {
          ...payload, // stored in state so the same call that is active in the datasource is made but for more records
          page: 0,
          batch: 1000, // You can set this to a any amount or variable
        },
      };
      const exportParams = {
        exportedRows: 'all',
        fileName: `listDataEported-${new Date().toString()}`,
        processCellCallback: (params) => valueFormatterFactory({ ...params, userPreferences }),
      };
      let error;

      try {
        const {
          data: {
            srListItems: { results: exportResults, totalNoOfRecords: totalNoOfExportedRecords },
          },
        } = await getData(fetchConfig);
        const currentRows = [...api.getRenderedNodes()]; // clone here to avoid immutable collision

        api.applyServerSideRowData({
          successParams: {
            rowData: exportResults,
            rowCount: totalNoOfExportedRecords,
          },
        });

        if (columnKeysToExport) {
          exportParams.columnKeys = columnKeysToExport;
        } else {
          exportParams.columnKeys = columnApi
            .getAllDisplayedColumns()
            .reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.colDef.exportable ? [...acc, curr.colId] : acc), []);
        }

        if (exportAs == 'csv') {
          api.csvCreator.exportDataAsCsv(exportParams);
        }

        if (exportAs == 'xlsx') {
          api.excelCreator.exportDataAsExcel(exportParams);
        }

        // sets the data back to what it was so the scroll bar doesn't lose its mind
        api.applyServerSideRowData({
          successParams: {
            rowData: currentRows,
            rowCount: totalNoOfRecords, // this is stored in state of datasource
          },
        });
      } catch (err) {
        error = err;
      } finally {
        setIsExportingListData(false);
        logResult({
          action: 'exportListData',
          component: 'useDataSource',
          error,
          meta: {
            ...fetchConfig.variables,
            exportAs,
            columnsExportedCount: exportParams?.columnKeys?.length || 0,
            columnsExported: exportParams?.columnKeys?.join(', ') || '',
            customExport: Boolean(columnKeysToExport),
          },
          eventName: error ? 'ERROR' : `EXPORT`,
        });
      }
    },
    [payload, totalNoOfRecords],
  );
```